# Avoiding race conditions and starvation with MongoDB + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, race-condition

I have a proxy management pool that is responsible for storing, checking, and retrieving proxies so that they can be used with web requests.

```
async getNextAvailableProxy() {
    while(true) {
        var sleepTime = global.Settings.ProxyPool.ProxySleepTimeMS;
        var availableProxies = await this.data.find(PROXY_COLLECTION, {
            $query: {
                Enabled: true,
                InUse: false,
                LastUsed: { $lte: new Date(new Date() - sleepTime) }
            },
            $orderby: { ResponseTime: 1 }
        });

        if (availableProxies.length <= 0) {
            var nextAvailable = await this.data.findOne(PROXY_COLLECTION, {
                $query: { Enabled: true, InUse: false },
                $orderby: { LastUsed: -1 }
            });

            if (!nextAvailable) {
                await Utils.sleep(100);
                console.log('No proxies available, sleeping');
                continue;
            }

            sleepTime = sleepTime - (new Date() - nextAvailable.LastUsed)
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                await Utils.sleep(sleepTime);

            continue;
        }

        var selectedProxy = availableProxies[0];
        selectedProxy.InUse = true;
        await this.data.save(PROXY_COLLECTION, selectedProxy);

        return selectedProxy;
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that my versions of `find` and `save` are wrappers around the MongoDB driver for NodeJS.

It is also worth noting that `Utils.sleep()` is a promise that uses a `setTimeout` to perform an async sleep.

Now, I understand that since NodeJS is single-threaded, race conditions cannot occur. However, when using multiple isolated objects querying the database rapidly, this is simply not the case.

If I have, say, five instances of object `ProxyPool` and they all call `getNextAvailableProxy()` within a short time of each other, they will all fetch the same proxy from the database, because one instance has already started the query before another instance has saved the `InUse` flag, leaving me with `n`-instances of `ProxyPool` all retrieving the save exact proxy.

How can I get around this in an asynchronous manner?

Comment: Out of curiosity; why are you doing this at all? Seems like something a good load balancer should be able to handle for you.

Comment: @Paul first attempt at a WebRequest subsystem with proxy support and custom features. If there is a better roadmap of how something like this should be done, I'm all ears

Comment: This is very racy.  You would need an atomic operation that checks for an available proxy, finds one and then marks it as in use - all in some atomic function.  I don't know mongo well enough to know how to do that with it, but I do know this is very racy and thus not reliable. All you need is two requests doing the `.find()` one right after another, both find one available, both set it as in use and now both are "using" the same slot which is not what you want.

Comment: @w0ffen that doesn't really tell me anything useful for helping you, sorry.  The definition of "webrequest subsystem with proxy support and custom features" is far too broad.  Is this a desktop, mobile, or web app?  What is it the subsystem of?  Why does it need to be proxy aware?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it's hard to tell why it's a problem based on your post.  While collisions can happen, it should be rare enough not to matter in my opinion, unless the use of the proxy is a really long running operation (and so a given proxy is tied up a lot).

That said, I also would not lookup a proxy on every request.  Instead, I'd probably have each worker fetch a pool of proxies either on startup or at intervals (maybe once an hour or something), and then internally manage (in-memory) the proxies it has available.

Your algorithm for figuring out what proxies to give a given worker can then be pretty flexible, and a lot less likely to have collisions, since each node instance is single threaded it won't allocate the same proxy twice.

The risk is that you may hit a place where a given worker has run out of proxies.  That's something you'll need to handle as well, but since you will (in theory) have your workers load balanced in some fashion, if you hit that spot you're probably running out of proxies anyway and will have to issue a `Too Busy` response soon.

Finally, when you do hit the DB for a list of available proxies, you should be using [findAndModify()](https://www.journaldev.com/6221/mongodb-findandmodify-example) or similar to fetch and update the documents in one shot, so that as you pull one out of the DB you tell the DB it's not available, rather than waiting on processing on your web server first.

Comment: My program is designed to have 'modules' that are each responsible for different data sources, but even with those different data sources I'd like to have each proxy rest between requests to avoid burning them out. Would it be viable to have one main `WebClient` and `ProxyPool` that is shared among all of the modules/workers and just store all of the requests in a queue?

Comment: So when I'm describing 'workers' I'm thinking of different node processes running, either as a cluster on one machine, or as multiple machines.  A module is different, it's just a way to organize code.  I'm also not sure what you mean by "proxy" anymore; are you talking about a network proxy, a reverse proxy, or something else?  Why does it need to "rest"?  It seems like you're throwing in a lot of stuff in the outset that may or may not be useful at all, and assuming your app has to solve all problems, when really there are infrastructure services you should rely on for much of this.

Comment: My project is essentially a data scraper/harvester that collects data from a bunch of different sources. In order to bypass rate limiting and quotas I have about 100 provate proxies that I am using to collect the data. I don't want to hammer these proxies to death, so I want to limit them to only one request per second, and I want these proxies shared among all of the workers. Each data source/worker will have its own process and communicate with a main process.

Comment: So you’re trying to defraud some data providers and violate their terms of service for your own ends,possibly affecting their ability to service paying customers by making tons of small requests from apparently different clients?  I think I’m done helping.

Comment: Defraud? No, I am not making money from this. All of the data is free, publicly available, and the Terms of Service states that bypassing the rate limit with proxies is frowned upon but not a violation as long as each proxy follows the IP rate limit rules as well. Regardless, thank you for taking the time to provide input.